# facebook PHP or Javascript get the user logged in info

Tags: javascript, php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I have a simple question : Can I get the username or some info of a user that is visiting my page if he is at the same time logged in at his facebook account?

I read about facebook graphe API but I'm not sure if it is requiring the user to login first into an app before we can get his info so basically I'm wondring if there is a PHP or javascript script that uses somehow facebook tools to detect if a visitor is logged in to facebook and catch his username if he is without asking him anything.

Thanks.

Comment: This is of course not possible, for a simple reason called “privacy”.

Answer (score 0):

No you can't get any information without permission of facebook user, he need to logged in your application and allow you to get information whatever you want.

If this is possible so i think no one use facebook api for getting information if user already logged in his fb account...

Comment: If it's impossible, why the comment system in Facebook is pulling all the users info without asking users for permission if users are logged it like in this page : [link](http://makemoneyonlinewithjohn.com/training/001qoc01.htm) try to add a comment when you are logged in to facebook to see.

Comment: you question is "can i get the username or some information", and simple is that you can't get information and store anywhere without permission of user, you have to use graph api for getting and saving any information, and for graph api, you need to take auth permissions...

Comment: I put a comment above saying that this page (in the link above) does not ask the user for anything permission it is detecting the facebbok logged in user automatically, I understand that I need to use facebook tools (API) the queston is : how can I do as that page is doing to get the user's info?